# eslint throwing parsing errors that do not exist

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm having a strange issue where when I try to run my project with "npm start" and there's an error, despite correcting that error, eslint will show the parsing error of the errenous time i tried to run it.

It's not recognizing that I changed the file and keeps showing the old error.  Nothing will get it to recognize the change in the file except deleting the node_modules folder and npm install again.

The only thing I can show is a screen shot.  You can see it thinks the file has the incorrect code when it's clearly changed.

Any ideas?  Using redux-toolkit and added the airbnb eslint

[image: Parsing error even though it doesn't exist]

Comment: @AjeetShah hi i don't think that has anything to do with my particular problem unfortunately, unless you can point me otherwise?  ty

Comment: @Ajeet Shah responded to your answer submission.  ty regardless